# If-Else Statement of Time in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Hi I successfully made the code in which I have the input of my computer time and date that goes like this

```
    function [Y, M, D, H, MN, S] = fcn()
    coder.extrinsic('now');
    coder.extrinsic('datevec');
    Y = 0;
    M = 0;
    D = 0;
    H = 0;
    MN = 0;
    S = 0;
   [Y, M, D, H, MN, S] = datevec(now);
   end
```

it works perfectly fine. Then I tried to make another block for the controller that will have an output of 1 between 7AM-5PM and output 0 if not within this time and my code goes like this

```
   function y = fcn(u)

   u = datestr(7:00AM:5:00PM)
  if u = datestr(7:00AM:5:00PM)
  y=1;
  else
   y=0;

  end
```

but an error occured. Please help me figure out what's wrong. Thank you

Comment: Comparisons need two equals: `if u == ...` not `if u =`

Comment: oh yea I actually forgot "==" in some of my codes.. thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the first function that you've made is already built in MATLAB as `clock`.

Regarding your problem, there are plenty of possible approaches to the problem, but I think the easiest one would be count seconds passed from the beginning of the day.

Using `clock` command you would get vector of current time in format: `[year month day hour minute second]`. So, the time passed from the beginning of day is `3600*time(4) + 60*time(5) + time(6)`, i.e. 3600 times hours plus 60 times minutes and plus seconds. From 00:00:00 to 7:00:00 7*3600 seconds passed. Similarly from 00:00:00 to 17:00:00 17*3600 seconds passed. Therefore, you can just compare these values to find whether it's between 7AM and 5PM or not:

```
function y = IsBetween5AMand7PM
    time = clock;
    current = 3600*time(4) + 60*time(5) + time(6); %seconds passed from the beginning of day until now
    morning = 3600*7; %seconds passed from the beginning of day until 7AM
    evening = 3600*17; %seconds passed from the beginning of day until 5PM
    y = current > morning && current < evening;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: this helps a lot.. and i mean A LOT! thank you so much.. hope I can ask questions to you in the future.. Thanks again

Comment: I triend the code and put in on a matlab function block of simulink and tried to have a display but an error seems to occur.. the first error goes like this "Undefined function or variable 'current'. The first assignment to a local variable determines its class."

Comment: @AsiongMartinez12 I do not know why Simulink does not understand the function. We declare `current` inside function, so there should not be issue. You might want to play with Model Parameters (InitFcn) in Simulink

Comment: the code finally works... Thank you so much for the help 